# JAVA: No way to get destination address of a received datagram packet?

Tags: java, udp

Searched a lot in the web, but seemed there is no way to let me know the destination address of a received datagram packet in Java.

My Java UDP server is running on a multiple interfaces host (most of them are virtual interfaces), so when the server received a packet, I need to get the packet's destination address, with which I would be able to create a socket that bind to this specific receiving address then use it to send the response.

```
socket = new DatagramSocket(12345);
socket.receve(packet);
/* here I need to bind the socket to the same address as that in
 * the destination part of the received packet.
 * But I found I can't ...
 */
socket.send(new DatagramPacket('data', len, packet.getSocketAddress());
```

I just cannot believe such a simple thing (in C) cannot be accomplished in Java. Could someone give me hint?  Thanks in advance!